# How to avoid error if element is not clickable at point (selenium python)?

Tags: python, selenium

I have this script that I wrote with selenium python, but sometimes I got this problem at this one place, when it shows that is not clickable. Element is there and it can be found but it can not be clickable, because sometimes I need to meet required conditions. See error bellow.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <div class=" css-1wa3eu0-placeholder"> is not clickable at point (242,476) because another element <div class="dropDownWrapper_artworkDetails_uaWNT"> obscures it
```

But when this happens I got error and script is stopped. So I need to start it again. Is it possible to do something like this (i did not found the way)...

```
if not clickable...at driver('selected class')
    driver.refresh()
else
    pass
```

This is my thinking, I was unable to find the way but maybe there is a special name or something. If you have any idea, any help is more then welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you wrap up the line of code within a `try-except{}` block and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  while True:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class$='placeholder']"))).click()
        break
    except TimeoutException:
        driver.refresh()
        continue
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  while True:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'placeholder')]"))).click()
        break
    except TimeoutException:
        driver.refresh()
        continue
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```